# NodeJS & Mongoose not returning documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this route that receives POST requests :

```
router.post('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if(err) 
            return res.json({success: false, msg: err});
        if(!user) 
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
        return res.json(user);
});
});
```

And this is my current collection's documents :

```
db.User.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d0e0465d91ce115f50935c"),
        "name" : "Soufiane",
        "email" : "example@gmail.com",
        "username" : "example",
        "password" : "123"
}
```

Using Restman, this is my request body :

```
{
    "username": "example",
    "password": "123"
}
```

But the result of is "User not found", this is my getUserByUsername function :

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = (_username, callback) => {
    const query = {username: _username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
};
```

The "User" model is connected to the correct database, and the connection Status = 1, i'm getting no error at the console, so what could be the problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the executed query ??

Comment: Which query ?the response of the Restman query ? If so this is the response :
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": "User not found"
}

Comment: Query produced by `User.findOne`

Comment: Can you print with console.log() the `err` and `user`  before the if statements. Just to know what returns the `getUserByUsername` function.

Comment: @PedroJimenez
Error : null, User : null

Comment: @SKJajoriya
It returns null for both user & error

Comment: Have you got the `username` in the function `getUserByUsername` ?

Comment: I can't see what could be the error, the code you are showing looks right to me. Can you verify that the user name you are  getting from the `req.body` is correct.

Comment: @SKJajoriya Yes getUserByUsername receives the username, i tried by adding a console.log and it successfully displays it

Comment: @PedroJimenez Yes the user on the req.body is correct, i don't understand as well because i'm following a video tutorial and doing the same as the video

Comment: I see that you are showing the list of users using `db.User.find` and inside the `getUserByUsername` you are using a mongoose model, in the mongoose schema are you using the correct collection? can you show the mongoose schema you are using?

Comment: `const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.getUserByUsername = (_username, callback) => {
    const query = {username: _username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
};`

Comment: @PedroJimenez And "show collections" command on mongodb returns the "User" collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the mongoose documentation says :

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model
>   is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your
>   model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the
>   tanks collection in the database.

I did not pay attention to this, since my model's name is User, i should have a collection called users, but all I had in my database was User, after creating the 'users' collections, everything worked out.